# Regular expression to match single parentheses

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

I need to parse excel formulas to generate C-compatible code. Now I need to parse the "power" expressions using Java:

```
1. F15^2
2. (A1*A2)^2
3. SQRT((A1*A2)^2)
```

I have the following regular expression:

```
(\([^)]*\)|\w+)\^(\([^)]*\)|\w+)
```

This expression parses 1. and 2. correctly.

```
1. Group1: F15, group2: 2
2. Group1: (A1*A2), group2: 2
```

However for 3. it returns 1 parenthesis too much:

```
3. Group1: ((A1*A2), group2: 2
```

How should I modify my regular expression so group 1 becomes (A1*A2) instead of ((A1*A2) ?

Comment: I think, replacing `[^)]` with `[^()]` could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding () should work

```
(\([^)^(]*\)|\w+)\^(\([^)^(]*\)|\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to work on these examples, I would change the regex to this: `(\([^)(]*\)|\w+)\^(\([^)]*\)|\w+)` (I added a single `(`)

But in general, I don't think a regex is the proper way to do it. I would try finding a library that could do parenthesis-parsing, instead of trying to implement it myself.